# powershell - copy specific user folders based on last modified

Tags: powershell

I need to copy the Documents, Favorites, and Desktop folders for each user that has logged in to the PC in the last 30 days.

I'm just starting to learn powershell and I've got a decent start I think, but I'm wasting too much time. This is a project for work, and I've found myself just digging for solutions to X problem only to run into another at the next turn. Spent about a month trying to get this sorted out thus far, and thrown away a lot of codes.

What I have as of right now is this:

```
Get-ChildItem -path c:\users |Where-Object  { $_.lastwritetime -gt (get-date).AddDays(-30)}
```

I know that this line will return the user folders that I need. At this point, I need code that will go in to each childitem from above and pull out the Documents, Favorites, and Desktop folder.

Now the tricky part. I need the code to create a folder on c: with the username it is pulling those folders from.

So the solution should:

for each user logged in in last 30 days;
copy Documents, Favorites, Desktop folder from their user drive
create a folder on c:\ for that user name
paste Documents, Favorites, Desktop to that folder

To better cover the scope:

I have to reimage PCs a lot in my department. The process of "inventorying" a PC is copying those folders and replacing them on the new PC I image for the user. That way their desktop etc looks the same and functions the same when they get their new PC. This code will be part of a larger code that ultimately "inventories" the entire PC for me... Ultimately, I want to be able to run my script for 2 seconds and then pull X folders and X documents off the c: drive on that PC as opposed to click, click, click, click a hundred times for 9 users that have used the PC in the last 30 days.

Any ideas?

2dubs

Comment: This is what USMT (User State Migration Tool) is for. Then you could define what to keep and ignore by defining rules(xml-file). You could also use the parameter `/uel 30` in the `scanstate` program (the process that captures the data) to make it exclude profiles older than 30 days. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj127984.aspx , http://blogs.technet.com/b/askds/archive/2011/05/05/usmt-and-u-migrating-only-fresh-domain-profiles.aspx

Comment: This isn't an option as the PCs we have deployed do not have the toolkit installed on them. I could download the toolkit on my own PC, but because of security restrictions, I cannot use powershell remotely. So if this were my solution, I'd have to transfer the script AND install the software on each PC I needed to back up.

Comment: You don't need to install anything on the clients AFAIK. You could copy the files to the compuer and you simply start `scanstate` to collect data and `loadstate` after windows is reinstalled. Copy + start the process can be done the same way that you're supposed to start the script your developing (psexec, logonscript, whatever). Also, depending on your OS deployment system (or manual routines), you could probably integrate it into the process itself.

Comment: I see what you mean, but it still poses a problem as the files are not already there. Hmmm. That may work because I could just transfer a package to the PC from the share drive and run the script that pulls from the package. But, I still have to transfer X many files where I'd much rather just have a solution that *bang* I run and then pull files off c: to my local PC then manipulate. Make sense? I'll definitely investigate this solution, though.

Comment: Apparently my facility GPO will not let me install the msi associated with this solution. This is not an option, but after some research on my end, this will likely be an option for anyone who CAN install this software if looking for a solution such as this. The path I was going to take was to create a folder that I can deploy to the PC and writing code such as what Frode has pointed out that will use the software associated with this solution to copy the stuff I need to the directory I want then just copying that entire folder to the PC I need to run the script on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Thanks to @bagger for his contribution. He was close.
```

After some experimentation, I found that this is the actual solution:

```
 $usersFoldr = Get-ChildItem -path c:\users | Where-Object  {   
$_.lastwritetime -gt (get-date).AddDays(-30)}
foreach ($f in $usersFoldr)
{

$doc = "c:\users\$f\documents"
  $toFldDoc = "c:\$f\documents"
  New-Item  $doc -type directory -force
  Copy-Item $doc $toFldDoc -recurse -Force 
  }

foreach ($f in $usersFoldr){
  $desk = "c:\users\$f\desktop"
  $toFldDesk = "c:\$f\desktop"
  New-Item  $desk -type directory -force
  Copy-Item $desk $toFldDesk -recurse -Force 
  }

foreach ($f in $usersFoldr){

$fav = "c:\users\$f\favorites"
 $toFldFav = "c:\$f\favorites"
 New-Item  $fav -type directory -force
  Copy-Item $fav $toFldFav -recurse -Force 
  }
```

Then save this file, send a shortcut of it to the desktop, then change the target of the shortcut to this:

C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -f "C:\YOURDIRECTORY\YOURSCRIPTNAME.ps1"

Then run that shortcut as an administrator. Works like gold.

Thanks for your help, guys! :)

**For anyone interested in the whole script:**
Inventory script to copy pertinent files for all users in last 30 days, gather printer hostname/driver/IP, gather serialnumber, gather make/model.

```
$usersFoldr = Get-ChildItem -path c:\users | Where-Object  {   
$_.lastwritetime -gt (get-date).AddDays(-30)}

foreach ($f in $usersFoldr){
  $doc = "c:\users\$f\documents"
  $toFldDoc = "c:\inventory\$f\documents"
  New-Item  $doc -type directory -force
  Copy-Item $doc $toFldDoc -recurse -Force 

    }

  foreach ($f in $usersFoldr){
   $desk = "c:\users\$f\desktop"
   $toFldDesk = "c:\inventory\$f\desktop"
   New-Item  $desk -type directory -force
   Copy-Item $desk $toFldDesk -recurse -Force 

    }

  foreach ($f in $usersFoldr){
   $fav = "c:\users\$f\favorites"
   $toFldFav = "c:\inventory\$f\favorites"
   New-Item  $fav -type directory -force
   Copy-Item $fav $toFldFav -recurse -Force 

    }

Get-WMIObject -class Win32_Printer | Select Name,DriverName,PortName 
|Export-CSV -path 'C:\Inventory\printers.csv'

Get-WmiObject win32_bios |foreach-object {$_.serialnumber} |out-file 
'c:\Inventory\SerialNumber.txt'

Get-WmiObject Win32_ComputerSystem | Select Model,Manufacturer |out-file 
'c:\Inventory\MakeModel.txt'
```

Again, save this file, send a shortcut of it to the desktop, then change the target of the shortcut to this:

C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -f "C:\YOURDIRECTORY\YOURSCRIPTNAME.ps1"

You can also retrieve a list of installed software by adding this line to the script:

```
get-wmiobject win32_product | select Name |export-csv -path 'c:\inventory
\software.csv'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$usersFoldr =  Get-ChildItem -path c:\users | Where-Object  {   $_.lastwritetime -gt (get-date).AddDays(-30)}

foreach ($f in $usersFoldr){
  $toFld = "c:usrTest\" + $f.Name +"\Desktop\"
  New-Item  $toFld -type directory -force
  Get-ChildItem ($f.FullName + "\Desktop") | Copy-Item -destination $toFld -Recurse -Force
 }
```

Comment: Perhaps I'm doing this wrong. I'm assuming that the XXX you have added is where I substitute a path. I have two problems with this.                                1 - how do I substitute the path across the user profile... IE: if I am a user as bobsmith then the path will be c:\users\bobsmith\documents... I tried to use your code and substitute the hypo bobsmith with $f and it seems like it works... not sure yet because when I run the code...                                       2 - I get everything in the sub folders of the directory I point to.

Comment: Here is the code.  `$usersFoldr = Get-ChildItem -path c:\users | Where-Object  {   $_.lastwritetime -gt (get-date).AddDays(-30)}

foreach ($f in $usersFoldr){
  $Fld = "c:\users\$f\documents" + $f.Name 
  $toFld = "c:\userbackup" + $f.Name +"\"
  New-Item  $Fld -type directory -force
  Copy-Item (Get-ChildItem $f.FullName -recurse | Where-Object  { $_.lastwritetime -gt (get-date).AddDays(-30)}).FullName  $toFld -recurse -Force 
  }`

Comment: Sorry I apparently fail at commenting on here. ^ that looks horrible. Either way, the result I get is that it DOES actually copy the Desktop folder that I need, but it copies EVERYTHING else too.

Comment: You might have some permission things to sort out.

Comment: I don't think that's the case. If I had permission issues, Powershell would return access denied or I wouldn't get anything at all in the return folder. At this point, I'm getting EVERYTHING in the return folder.

Comment: Changed your code and got permission issues.

`foreach ($f in $usersFoldr){
  $Fld = "c:\users\%username%\documents" + $f.Name`  

gives me access denied. When I save the script and execute in powershell as admin, it does the same thing -- returns ALL the files and folders in the user folder specified by the code.